# WORDPRESS: Redirect a user if they are not logged in, ONLY if they are on a certain page

Tags: php, wordpress

I've tried multiple ways/plugins and edits to my functions.php file, however, I can't figure out or find a way which has worked for me. I was able to redirect when the user visits the page in question, however I am unable to limit this to only if they're not logged in.

My users will visit the slug:

```
example.com/feature-page/
```

Then if they're not logged in, I'd like to redirect them to:

```
example.com/dashboard/
```

If you have a solution, I'd be happy to hear. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your header(header.php) and it should work fine.

```
if(!is_user_logged_in()&&is_page('feature-page')) {
  header("Location: http://www.example.com/dashboard/"); 
  //remember to replace "example.com" with your domain
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function for this built into wordpress:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in

```
if(!is_user_logged_in()) {
  // user is not logged in
  // execute your code here
}
```

Comment: I know, this is one of the functions I was experimenting with to get it to work, but with this function there's no way to detect what page a user is on, thus making this only 50% of what I needed.

Comment: So you use two functions. Lol... You marked the other guy as best answer, so clearly I answered your question. I just expected you knew how to detect the page already since you clearly stated `I was able to redirect when the user visits the page in question`. I didn't realize you needed someone to hold your hand and write something so basic for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using `wp_redirect()` function to redirect and check user is login or not for `is_user_logged_in()` function to login or not login user redirect. e.g.

```
if(is_user_logged_in()) {
 wp_redirect( get_permalink( $your_page_ID )); exit;
#example.com/dashboard/

}
else{
wp_redirect(home_url()); exit;
#example.com/feature-page/

}
```